# Controlling WIT visibility across backlogs

Tags: tfs

I know this has to have been asked and answered, but I'm struggling to find the answer.

What I want to do is simple in my mind.  I want User Stories that are in a completed state to show on up my Iteration backlogs but not on the Product backlog.

I have a custom Completed state that I have mapped to the InProgress state for my RequirementBacklog.  That allows stories in the Completed state to show up on the Iteration backlog, but it results in the stories also showing up on the Product backlog.

How can I separate these two things?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not able to separate them.